# Regex Matching on a c# method call, and changing the value of the parameters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to iterate of a c# source file and update some things so I need a regex that will match if it finds a method call in the string that's passed.

I'm planning on iterating over each line, and passing the individual line to the regex.  I'm not bothered about calls that pass over 2 lines right now.

What I need is to replace certain things if conditions are met.

So, a method call would look like this:

```
<some text> object.object.object.method(param1, param2, param3);
```

1. The object. part could be repeated any number of times.  I don't mind simply catching this in a single one.
2. There could be any number of parameters, and these could, themselves include a method call that should be matched.
3. The param part could be empty and I need to check this

e.g.

```
value = object.method(param1, , param3);
```

Note: I appreciate that this isn't valid c# code, that is part of the reason I'm doing the parsing.

What I need to do is replace any the paramX values, and possibly update the object.object.object.method part.

I need to do this in C# code, I don't mind the method, but I want to extend on this for further parsing/changing in the future, so an explanation of the methodology would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've written a C# preprocessor that does various manipulations to a C# program, and I can tell you that it is not as simple as it first looks. For example, what about generic type specifications? What about the different kinds of string and numerical constants that may be used as parameters? What about expressions as parameters? My advice (which you may have already decided) is that you will only accept a very simplified and stylized kind of C#.

Comment: @RenniePet thanks, this has a very specific purpose, and it's parse some code that I'm migrating from VB.NET that the convertors output  simply wrong (i.e. VB allows an empty parameter if it's optional, and the convertor assumes that you can do that in c#).  I have a lot of files to convert, and it's very repetitive to do these sorts of things.

Comment: Still, I think it might be an idea to look into non-regex possibilities, like a lexical parser. http://goldparser.org/ http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Compilers/Lexer_and_Parser_Generators/ Or could Roslyn be applied to this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818501.aspx

Comment: Essentially, there are a lot of lines like `oData.GetParam("blah", , "blah1");` and all I need to do is find where the method is GetParam, and then add "50" into the space.  So I don't think that creating something like that is worth the hassle.